# Adding data to div via ajax

Tags: php, ajax, json, mysqli

Afternoon

My php and Ajax is now almost complete, but I'm stuck on one thing I'm getting the data sent back through to the ajax but its only showing [object Object] in the div I've specified and I'm wanting the number of results sent back to be in there.

```
<?  $call="SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE notification_targetuser='$user1_id' ORDER BY notification_id DESC LIMIT 1";
        $chant=mysqli_query($mysqli,$call) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
        $num=mysqli_num_rows($chant);


            while($notification_id=mysqli_fetch_array($chant))
            {
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function(){


  var notification_id="<?php echo $notification_id['notification_id'] ;?>"

$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "viewajax.php?notification_id="+notification_id,   
dataType:"json",
cache: false,
success: function(response){
$("#mes").prepend(response);

}
});
},20000);

</script>
<? }?>
```

Vuewajax.php

```
<?php

 include"database.php";

if(isset($_GET['notification_id'])){

$id=$_GET['notification_id'];
$user1_id=$_SESSION['id'];
$json = array();
$com=mysqli_query($mysqli,"select notification_id from notifications where notification_id > '$id'");
echo mysqli_error($mysqli);

$num = mysqli_num_rows($com);
if($num>0){

    echo '<span id="mes">'.$num.'</span>';
}
$resultArr = mysqli_fetch_array($com);
$json['notification_id'] = $resultArr['notification_id'];

mysqli_free_result($com);


echo json_encode($json);
}
 ?>
```

My returned response in firebug

```
<span id="mes">1</span>{"notification_id":"3306"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a json object, so you need to access the correct propery, in this case `notification_id`. Its also good practice to set the correct content-type header:

```
//php set json header
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);

//js access property of returned object
$("#mes").prepend(response.notification_id);
```

EDIT as per comment - if you are sending json, only send json, not mixed in html:

```
if($num>0){

    $json['num'] = $num;
}else{
    $json['num'] = 0;
}
$resultArr = mysqli_fetch_array($com);
$json['notification_id'] = $resultArr['notification_id'];

mysqli_free_result($com);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);


//js
 $("#mes").prepend('<span id="mes">'+ response.num + '</span>');
```

Further EDIT
You can check the value of num, and only prepend if its not 0. As 0 evaluates to false, the following will work

```
if(response.num){
     $("#mes").prepend('<span id="mes">'+ response.num + '</span>');
}
```

Comment: I'm just needing the actual number of records out of the php that are sent back to be inserted into its div

`<span id="mes">1</span>`
Notification_id is only there to find the next available id.

Comment: Fantastic, it works.And as simple as my stupid rookie error of mixing them both. Thanks so much.

Comment: How would I go about showing nothing at all if there is no data? as it throws back undefined in the div if there is no result if I add `echo"";`

Answer (score 1):

This answer can seems to be off-topic but the code you show us is not secure. He's prone to easy [sql injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

eg :

```
$id  = $_GET['notification_id'];
$com = mysqli_query($mysqli,"select notification_id from notifications where notification_id > '$id'");
```

Injecting "*'; DELETE FROM users WHERE 1 or username = ''*" in your notification_id parameter will delete all your users !

Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), it's easy and far safer an [XKCD](http://xkcd.com/327/) ;-)

Comment: You're right. But I don't secure my scripts until I have got them working :P

Comment: As an experimented (?) developer, I know that what is not done first shot is difficult to get done once your in a hurry ! It's true for security, documentation and testing. Believe me.